# How to retry if web services are down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I tried to retry when the web service failed.

I was using spring retry, but with spring retry I can't specify the status code based retry

This is my code

```
    @retryable(value=Exception.class,maxAttampts=2)
 Public void retry() throws exception {  
System.out.println("retry started") 
throw new exception}
```

I invoked the retry() method in my webservice class.

Comment: Retryable can specify exactly which exceptions will cause a retry, so you just need to convert the HTTP response to some specific exception type. `@Retryable(MyHttp500Exception.class, ...)`

Comment: @Michael without create user defined exception any way are  there!!

Answer (score 0):

Spring retry has the following structure.

```
@Retryable(
    value = {IllegalArgumentException.class},
    maxAttempts = 5,
    backoff = @Backoff(1000)
  )
```

It will work when there is a specific exception. It does not work based upon the custom value. In your case, if the status code like 200 or 201 is not retrieved from a service, then you can throw an exception or your custom exception for which you can perform this retry operation. It works only on exceptional cases I mean for exception.Any value can be transformed into an exception to perform retry operation.

you can refer the following link.
https://github.com/debjava/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ddlab/rnd/MyServiceImpl.java